# cannot read property '<fieldname>' of null after some time running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I have an angularjs website with NodeJS socket methods as a client, and a NodeJS application as a server.

Data is being passed from the server to the client through socket events. The problem is that after working fine for about 5 minutes, intermittently data that is successfully being sent from the NodeJS server is being received as 'null' in the website, thus giving me the following error:

```
angular.js:11598 TypeError: Cannot read property '<fieldName>' of null
    at ecabsAngular.js:42
    at angular.js:12149
    at angular.js:12137
    at angular.js:12137
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:12837)
    at l.$digest (angular.js:14222)
    at l.$apply (angular.js:14493)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (ecabsAngular.js:275)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (socket.io-1.2.0.js:1)
    at Socket.onevent (socket.io-1.2.0.js:1)
```

Do you have any idea what is causing this and how this can be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
This is the code that is crashing on the client side (on the website)

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('Module', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
            $scope.bookings = [];

            socket.on('updateBooking', function(booking){
                $scope.loadAllocations();
                for (var i=0; i<$scope.bookings.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.bookings[i].CRMBookingID == booking.CRMBookingID) {
                        $scope.$apply(function(){
                            $scope.bookings[i] = booking;                           
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    ]);

})();
```

This is the code from the NodeJS (server):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 200;
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var sql = require('mssql');
server.listen(3000);                       

app.post('/updatebooking', function(request, response)                      // receive web service request
{
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});              // build response header
    response.end();                                                         // end the response
    request.on('data', function(changes) 
    {
        try{
            var c = JSON.parse(changes.toString());                         // parse data received
            var connection = new sql.Connection(config);                    // create DB connection

            connection.connect(function (err)                               // connect to the database
            {
                if (err!=null) {   logger.error('Update booking connection error: ' + c + ' ' + err);   }

                var request = new sql.Request(connection);                  // create SQL request
                request.stream = true; 

                try{
                    var sqlquery = <sqlquery>;                              // build SQL query
                    logger.trace("Executing SP in DB: " + sqlquery);
                    request.query(sqlquery);                                // execute SP
                    request.on('row', function (row)                        // once committed send to the client (website)
                    {
                        logger.trace("Updated booking with Reference ID " + row.Ref + " " + sqlquery);
                        io.emit('updateBooking', row);                      // sending data
                    })
                    request.on('error', function(err) {
                        logger.error('Update booking SP request error: ' + sqlquery + err);
                    });
                }catch( e){
                    logger.error('Update booking request error' + sqlquery + ' ' + e);
                }

            }); 
        } catch(e)
        {
            var c = JSON.parse(changes.toString());
            logger.error('Update booking error for: ' + c + ' ' +e);
        }
        connection.on('error', function(err) {
            logger.error('Update error connection: ' + err);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Share your piece of code where this is crashing.

Comment: this was being encountered due to errors appearing in the browser console. Once the errors were handled everything continued to work normally.